# Code for analog joystick mod wheel do nothing

Tags: function, reaper

This script is to get an analog joystick to emulate a midi mod wheel on vertical axis and a pitch blend on the horizontal axis but when i test it i have only the pitch blend working but the mod wheel do nothing.

Here the code :

```
// buttons (bitmask), numbuttons (valid bits in buttons)
// systime (time in seconds)
// axis(x), numaxis (number actually supported)
// pov(x), numpov, pov(x) > 360 if not pointing

// event(msg1,msg2,msg3) to send events

// settings
joystick_modwheel_axis = 2; 
joystick_pitchblend_axis = 1; 
midi_channel  = 0; // 0-15
modwheel_cc   = 1; // 0-127
pitchblend_cc = 2; // 0-127

modwheel_val = floor(abs(axis(joystick_modwheel_axis) * 127));
pitchblend_val = floor((axis(joystick_pitchblend_axis) * 8192) + 8192);

modwheel_val != modwheel_val_old ? (
  event($xb0 | midi_channel, modwheel_cc, modwheel_val);
  modwheel_val_old = modwheel_val;
);

pitchblend_val != pitchblend_val_old ? (
  event($xe0 | midi_channel, pitchblend_val & 0x7F, pitchblend_val >> 7);
  pitchblend_val_old = pitchblend_val;
);
```

I have include a schematic of the functions needed :[image]

I have tried various axis change and nothing seem to work.

Comment: This is not lua.

Comment: My mistake it is c++ and i am a beginner sorry. Is there a way to transfer this post in the correct section?

Comment: This is not c++ either, is this just some pseudocode or a dedicated script working on an engine? You can edit the tag of the question.

Comment: Well the script come from the Reaper DAW so my guess was it was either lua or c but i know they use EEL2 so maybe this is what it is.